# Node mongodb driver can insert, count, but find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am migrating an existing  app to mongodb,

I have this code mostly found on the node native mongodb driver site.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./configuration/mongo.json", "utf-8").toString());
const assert = require('assert');


const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    // Insert some documents
    collection.insertMany([
        {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
    ], function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
        assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
        console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
        callback(result);
    });
};


const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs)
        callback(docs);
    });
};
function initDb() {

    var uri = "mongodb://" + mongoConfig.user + ":" + mongoConfig.pass + "@" + mongoConfig.host + ":" + mongoConfig.port;
    MongoClient.connect(uri, {auth: {user: mongoConfig.user, password: mongoConfig.pass}, authSource: mongoConfig.dbname}, function (err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        const db = client.db('test');

        insertDocuments(db, function() {
            findDocuments(db, function() {
                client.close();
            });

        });
}

initDb();
```

Then i get the following output in the console :

```
Inserted 3 documents into the collection
Found the following records
[]
```

Using Robomongo from the same computer to the same server using same credentials, i am able to see and edit the datas.

the insert is working fine, as i am writing this i have a dozen of test documents inserted this way.

But find allways return an empty array.
However, using count instaed of toArray returns the corret value.

I am using : 
   "mongodb": "^3.0.5",

From my package.json

What am i missing pls ?

Comment: I tryed to downgrade my nodejs server to 6.x.x (previously 8.x.x) sice Node mongo driver does not support node server up to 6.x.x (according to the documentation). But no better result. Anyone an idea ?